# React component: video running, but stream not run through methods

Tags: reactjs, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I have a react component which should be outputting predictions, in the form of bounding boxes. Right now, there *is* video showing up on the page for the component, but unfortunately, there are **0** bounding boxes; when i log the output, nothing is coming out. But the model is, loading, as im logging the type. So, i'm not sure where it is off.

Codesandbox for reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-hellman-18f2e

Here is the react component:

```
const cocoSsd = require("@tensorflow-models/coco-ssd");

class CamBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.videoRef = React.createRef();
    this.canvasRef = React.createRef();
    this.canvasRef.current = document.createElement("video");

    this.videoRef.current = document.createElement("video");

    this.detectFromVideoFrame = (model, video) => {
      model.detect(video).then(
        predictions => {
          this.showDetections(predictions);

          requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            this.detectFromVideoFrame(model, video);
          });
        },
        error => {
          console.log("Couldn't start the webcam");
          console.error(error);
        }
      );
      this.showDetections = predictions => {
        const ctx = this.canvasRef.current.getContext("2d");
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
        const font = "24px helvetica";
        ctx.font = font;
        ctx.textBaseline = "top";

        predictions.forEach(prediction => {
          const x = prediction.bbox[0];
          const y = prediction.bbox[1];
          const width = prediction.bbox[2];
          const height = prediction.bbox[3];
          // Draw the bounding box.
          ctx.strokeStyle = "#2fff00";
          ctx.lineWidth = 1;
          ctx.strokeRect(x, y, width, height);
          // Draw the label background.
          ctx.fillStyle = "#2fff00";
          const textWidth = ctx.measureText(prediction.class).width;
          const textHeight = parseInt(font, 10);
          // draw top left rectangle
          ctx.fillRect(x, y, textWidth + 10, textHeight + 10);
          // draw bottom left rectangle
          ctx.fillRect(
            x,
            y + height - textHeight,
            textWidth + 15,
            textHeight + 10
          );

          // Draw the text last to ensure it's on top.
          ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
          ctx.fillText(prediction.class, x, y);
          ctx.fillText(prediction.score.toFixed(2), x, y + height - textHeight);
        });
      };
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
      // define a Promise that'll be used to load the webcam and read its frames
      const webcamPromise = navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({
          video: true,
          audio: true
        })

        .then(
          stream => {
            window.stream = stream;
            // pass the stream to the videoRef
            this.videoRef.current.srcObject = window.stream;
            return new Promise(resolve => {
              this.videoRef.current.onloadedmetadata = () => {
                resolve();
              };
            });
          },
          error => {
            console.log("Couldn't start the webcam");
            console.error(error);
          }
        );

      // define a Promise that'll be used to load the model

      const loadlModelPromise = cocoSsd.load();

      // resolve all the Promises
      Promise.all([loadlModelPromise, webcamPromise])
        .then(values => {
          this.detectFromVideoFrame(values[0], this.videoRef.current);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log(cocoSsd.version);
    return (
      <div className="CamMonitor">
        <div className="videoJawn" style={{ transform: "translate(0px,0px)" }}>
          <video
            className="innerVideo"
            autoPlay
            muted
            ref={this.videoRef}
            width="500"
            height="360"
          />
          <canvas
            style={this.styles}
            ref={this.canvasRef}
            width="20"
            height="50"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CamBox;
```

The video seems to be working fine, and i am logging the cocossd version, so its loaded, but its not running any predictions. I've been working on this bug for 2 days, and any help is so appreciated!
Codesandbox for reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-hellman-18f2e

Comment: There is no point in duplicating the question multiple times

Comment: okay; i thought by adding a sandbox and rephrasing question would help and that reposting would ive opportunity for other to see, as i had not gotten many responses with suggested edits. i will delete the other. thanks.

Comment: you can just consider editing the question

Comment: thank you @edkeveked, i will next time.

Answer (score 1):

The element is being drawn on the canvas. But it is not displayed for two reasons:

- The canvas dimensions are small (50 and 20)
- the overflow property is set to hidden

```css
.videoJawn {
  height: 445px;
  width: 405px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  border-radius: 19px;

  overflow: auto; /*or scroll */
}
```

Comment: a single canvas is appearing but it still does not seem to be classifying anything.

Comment: I tried recording myself and I saw `person` written on the canvas with the green box drawn moving. So I don't know what you are talking about by saying that nothing is being classified. However the canvas does not have the image of the video displayed because you did not copy that image to the canvas before drawing